# How to make a native windows splash screen with Flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-windows

I know how to make a **native splash screen** for Android, iOS, and Web, as it is covered in [Flutter official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) and [in this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash).

So how to make a native splash screen when deploying for **Windows**?

*Note: I am talking about the blank/white screen that appears before flutter is loaded, so it needs to be native only (no dart solution).*

Comment: I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5731) with Flutter requesting this documentation. Please give it a thumbs up to give it more visibility with the Flutter team.

Comment: The opened issue for this is now [this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41980).